# Gerrit: Fixing commit without change-id in footer

Tags: git, gerrit

I have Gerrit set up to require change-id in the commit message footer. But, I was able to somehow push a change without a change-id in the footer. That seems to have messed up my branch (master branch). I am unable to push to the master branch now.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean

> touch test.txt

> git add .

> git commit

> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   test.txt

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v origin master:refs/for/master 
Pushing to ssh://username@gerrit.site.com:29418/project_name
To ssh://username@gerrit.site.com:29418/project_name
 ! [rejected]        master -> refs/for/master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://username@gerrit.site.com:29418/project_name'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
Completed with errors, see above
```

and here is the structure of the branches:

```
o [origin/master][origin/HEAD][master] current head
\ \
 \ \
  \ o commit without change-id in footer
   \
    o [origin/refs/for/master] test commit to try and fix previous
```

Comment: Are you using sourcetree? Is your issue related to this bug: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-2940 ?

Comment: I do use SourceTree but I've taken that into account. I am able to push to other branches just fine.

Comment: First: the "git commit" is missing in your question, is this correct? Second: is there any chance you have created by mistake a branch called "refs/for/master"? You can verify this at Projects > select_project > branches.

Comment: Yes, you are right on both.

Comment: Uhm... I have added an answer. If you have any issue let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's divide your question in two topics:

**Commit without the Change-Id**

You have pushed the commit straight to branch bypassing Gerrit. This is accomplished by executing, for exemple, one of the following commands:

git push origin master:master

OR

git push origin master:refs/heads/master

When you push straight to branch, the Change-Id is not required because Gerrit was bypassed in the process. The only way to avoid this mistake is remove your permission to push to refs/heads/* (straight to branch).

**Error pushing to refs/for/master**

It seems that you have created, by mistake, a branch called "refs/for/master". I think this issue would happen if you, for example, executed a command like this:

```
git push origin master:refs/heads/refs/for/master
```

In this case, to fix the issue just remove the wrong branch using the Gerrit UI:

1. Go to Projects > List
2. Use the "Filter" field to find your project
3. Click on project name
4. Click on "Branches" tab
5. Select the "refs/for/master" branch
6. Click on "Delete" button

Comment: Thanks Marcelo. I've added some additional details. In trying to fix the original error, I ended up creating a new branch (origin/refs/for/master). Your solution would fix one of the issues, not the other. Also, I still don't understand why I was able to push through a commit without a change-id in the footer.

Comment: Was the "commit-without-change-id" pushed to Gerrit? Was the change created? What is the change status? You have not pushed straight to branch bypassing Gerrit by mistake, have you? Note: if you bypass Gerrit Change-Id presence is not checked.

Comment: Yes, the commit was pushed to Gerrit and was "accepted" without review. I did not intentionally bypass Gerrit but it seems that's what has happened.

Comment: Yes, there's no Change-Id check in this case. It's not a good idea to have permission to push straight to Gerrit due to some mistakes that could happen. I updated my answer about this subject.

Comment: Is there a way to delete the commit without change-id in footer?

Comment: No, you can't delete a commit after it was integrated (submitted or pushed straight to branch). You can, of course, reverse the commit (do another commit which removes the change made by the previous one).

Comment: You can revert the commit using 'git revert' (see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert.html), push to gerrit, review, merge.

I always use "git log" before push to verify in my tiny brain what is about to be pushed; I often use "git push --dry-run", git prints diagnostics indicating what will be pushed but without changing anything on the server.

As @MarceloÁviladeOliveira mentioned "it's not a good idea to have permission" pushing branches directly, use the Gerrit admin interface (see https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_push) to restrict it.